# Fade between unlimited number of images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of images

`<img src="test.png" />
<img src="test.png" />
<img src="test.png" />`

I would like to fade between each image. 
Should take three seconds for each fade.
The number of images is not pre-set - There might be 3 or 10 or 30

How can I do that using css/html?

Thank you.

Here's what I tried:

`
    .canvas-section-glideshow > img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        color: transparent;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    }

```
.canvas-section-glideshow > img:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.canvas-section-glideshow > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.canvas-section-glideshow > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.canvas-section-glideshow > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something similar to what you're looking for on W3 schools.
I'm not too sure if you can do it with only html and css, but I know you can with some JS.

Here's a simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/m2ks65h9/

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

    <div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" alt="img1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="img2" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" alt="img3" style="width:100%">
  </div>

</div>

    var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```